# RegExp, вырезания строки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть такие кейсы:

```
 '123*45?=5?088' // надо 123
  '-5?*-1=5?', // надо -5?
  '19--45=5?', // надо 19
  '??*??=302?',// надо ??
  '?*11=??',  // надо ?
```

Что мне нужно? Я хочу вырезать первую подстроку т.е мне нужно вырезать до первого знака. Как сделать это с помощю регулярных выражений.

Comment: а почему "до первого знака" и "надо 19-" и "-5?"

Comment: потому что мне надо иметь минусовые числа.Типа -5 не должно быть как знак минус и отдельно 5.А как отдельное отрицательное число

Comment: А что на счёт `19-`?

Comment: опечаточка вышла

Comment: Знаки только простые? Т.е. `+`,  `-`,  `*`,  `/`

Comment: Да.Только простые знаки

Comment: ```/^(-?[\d\?]+)/gi```  https://regex101.com/r/tPx2Yx/1 .... з.ы. маленькая правочка, вот так будет точнее ```/(^-?\?*[\d]*\?*)/gm```

Comment: спасибо.На regex101 работает но в моём коде почему-то нет.Есть у кого догадки?

Comment: const regularka = new RegExp(`/^(-?[\\d\\?]+)/gi`)

    const firstSubString = `?*11=??`.split(regularka)
    console.log(firstSubString)

Comment: мой аутпут * [ '?*11=??' ]

Comment: Конечно есть, вы забираете всю строку, а не найденную в ней часть.

Comment: тобишь я должен добавить по типу const firstSubString = exp.split(regularka)[0]?Это ситуацию не меняет

Comment: ```const regularka = new RegExp(/(^-?\?*[\d]*\?*)/gm);
let x = "?*11=??".split(regularka)[1]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Регулярка:

```
/(^-?\?*[\d]*\?*)/gm

"()" - группа, значение которое нам нужно получить
"^" - начало строки
"-" - знак минуса с модификатором "?"(не обязательность)
"\?" - знак вопроса, с модификатором количества "*"(0 и более символов)
"[\d]" - любая цифра, с модификатором количества "*"(0 и более символов)
"\?" - знак вопроса, с модификатором количества "*"(0 и более символов)

/g - поиск по всему тексту
/m - поиск в каждой строке как в отдельной части(^ - указывает на начало строки с таким модификатором, а не на начало всего текста).
```

Пример на js:

```js
const regularka = new RegExp(/(^-?\?*[\d]*\?*)/gm);

let x = "?*11=??".split(regularka)[1];
console.log(x);

x = "-9?+11=??/dfgdf 99+11".split(regularka)[1];
console.log(x);
```

p.s. в комментариях дополнили, если знак вопроса - является частью числа и может быть в любом месте - регулярка будет намного проще:

```
/(^-?[\d?]+)/gm
"()" - группа, значение которое нам нужно получить
"^" - начало строки
"-" - знак минуса с модификатором "?"(не обязательность)
"[\d\?]" - любая цифра или знак вопроса, с модификатором количества "+"(1 и более символов)
```

Comment: Было бы супер, если бы вы ещё работающий код приложили для данных примеров для наглдяности)))

Comment: @EzioMercer забирайте, мне не жалко :)

Comment: Благодарю вас,сэр.Как также шарить в RegExp?))

Comment: Было бы вообще идеально, если бы вы вставили код как запускаемый код (ctrl+m в редакторе вопроса) 

Comment: @EzioMercer можете поправить мой вопрос, маркдаун не мой конек, не помню как там язык указывать :)

Comment: @MarkushaBoec прочитать учебник по регуляркам и запомнить основные вещи? или вы думаете знания которые содержаться в ответе почерпнуты не из первой попавшейся статьи?

Comment: А как насчет 1?23*45?=5?088   этого?)

Comment: ```(^-?[\d\?]*)``` вот так например.

Comment: Не успел)) Но я к тому и оставил комбинацию, чтобы не мучаться со спецификой маркдауна))

Comment: Cпасибо.Иду учиться))

Comment: @MarkushaBoec дополнил ответ, в нем более верная запись (перестанет находить "пустые" строки)

Comment: Super.Спасибо :)

Comment: @MarkushaBoec Не забываем отмечать полезные ответ голосом за (знаю что сейчас репутации ен хватит, просто на будущее), а правильный ответ галочкой :)

Comment: А как галочку сделать?

Comment: @MarkushaBoec
Рядом с рейтингом ответа у вас есть серая галочка, нажмете - станет зеленой и ответ будет помечен как верный. https://ibb.co/5nbvfkf

Comment: спасибо)Учту на будущее